# Stacking arrays of unequal shape

Tags: arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

```
 `print(np.array([arr[2:4], arr[3:5]])) # same shape`
```

I can do stacking in the above cases to get a 3d array so that I can train LSTM network.
But I have array of 2d arrays of unequal length. Like:
`

```
print(np.array([arr[:2], arr[:3]]))
[array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]])
 array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5]])]
```

`
How can I get a 3d array in this case so that I can train my LSTM network?
Please help.
If there are some alternatives please mention .

Comment: You have to understand the network.  Padding, or scaling,could introduce artifacts that reduce the quality of the learning.  Go back to the theory.  Why does the network expect a consistent size?

Answer (score 0):

For LSTM input, to batch your sequences you need the same size of mini-batches. For that you can use [`np.pad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html#numpy-pad) to make it each same size. Usually you will pad with zero.

```py
>>> a = np.pad(a, pad_width=[(0,1),(0,0)])    # pad by zeros
>>> a
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [0, 0]])
>>> b
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5]])

>>> np.stack([a,b])
array([[[0, 1],
        [2, 3],
        [0, 0]],

       [[0, 1],
        [2, 3],
        [4, 5]]])
```

***Parameter***

> pad_width : {sequence, array_like, int}

- Number of values padded to the edges of each axis. ((before_1, after_1), … (before_N, after_N)) unique pad widths for each axis. ((before, after),) yields same before and after pad for each axis. (pad,) or int is a shortcut for before = after = pad width for all axes.

  ---

For other options see [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2375)